# Unable to findout vowel count using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find out ID numbers where the number of vowels in the body is an even number for the URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

My code is given below:

```
import json

import requests

   
url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
content = requests.get(url).content

j = json.loads(content)
for each in j:

        print(each['id'],each['body'])
```

I am now able to print the body for each user ID but unable to find out the number of vowels in the body which is an even number. Need help

Comment: You didn't show your attempt at solving the problem - count the vowels. Please, update your code to include your attempt and explain the problem. Check [ask]

Comment: As a side note you can use convenience `json()` method of `requests.Response` object, no need to use `json` module.

Answer (score 3):

You can count vowels with this code:

```
print(*map(each['body'].lower().count, "aeiou"))
```

whole code:

```
import json

import requests

   
url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
content = requests.get(url).content

id_even = []
j = json.loads(content)
for each in j:
    cnt_vwl = 0
    for c in "aeiou":
        cnt_vwl += each['body'].lower().count(c)
    if cnt_vwl%2==0:
        id_even.append(each['id'])
id_even
```

Output: *(id that each['body'] have even vowels)*

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10,...]
```

Comment: using this approach is not so efficient as you need to convert to lower and parse the text again for each letter

Comment: @mozway do you say with this solution we need five iteration each text?

Comment: Yes, it will first shift all characters to lowercase and check all characters to count the "a"s, then again for each letter

Comment: But it didn't show the even number as asked?

Comment: @mozway yes you say right but in computing order we know in this code have order with `O(C*N)` and C is consistency and in this code `C=5` and we know C=5 is not bad

Comment: @ShaonPaul Ohh, I forgot, I fix it now

Comment: @user1740577 so you mean if you can make a code 5 times more efficient, it is not worth it? ;)

Comment: @ShaonPaul edited answer and you can see vowel with count that have even count

Comment: @mozway I don't say, In `big-O` computing and programming we know for large and big data is important but for small data is not very matter

Comment: @user1740577 , I think it shows the vowel count for even number, but as asked, user wants to show the ID numbers where the number of vowels in body is an even

Comment: @user1740577 as I understand user wants to count the total vowel count for each Id, not as an individual  line, and if the total vowel count within the body is even then print that ID number.

Comment: @user1740577, great job. This is the exact answer I believe.

Comment: @ShaonPaul have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a list comprehension and `re.sub` to keep only the vowels:

```
import re

ids_even_vowels = [i['id']
                   for i in j if i['body']
                   if not len(re.sub('[^aeiouy]', '', i['body'], flags=re.I))%2==1
                  ]
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 27, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 40, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 73, 76, 78, 82, 84, 90, 92, 95, 96, 97, 99]
```

#### how counting the vowels works:

```
>>> my_string = 'AbCDefGHI'

>>> re.sub('[^aeiouy]', '', my_string, flags=re.I)
'AeI'   # vowels only

>>> len(re.sub('[^aeiouy]', '', my_string, flags=re.I))
3       # number of vowels

>>> len(re.sub('[^aeiouy]', '', my_string, flags=re.I))%2
1       # remainder of division by 2: 1 is odd, 0 is even

>>> not len(re.sub('[^aeiouy]', '', my_string, flags=re.I))%2
False   # is it even?
```